# Lock + suspend behavior on laptop lid close

Tags: 16.04, suspend, lock-screen, i3-wm, lid

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 on two different laptops:

- Lenovo Thinkpad T460s
- HP Probook 6470b

My configuration is similar across both laptops. I have i3 WM installed, with lightdm (the default on 16.04).

In Unity, when closing the lid, lock+suspend works fine on both laptops.

In i3 WM, the behavior changes between both laptops:

- On the T460s, when I close the lid, the laptop locks + suspends. The lock screen is the gnome-screensaver e.g. `gnome-screensaver-command -l`.
- On the Probook, when I close the lid, the laptop only suspends. It doesn't lock.

Where is the "lock + suspend on lid close" behavior defined?

**Extra information:**

I spent some time trying to find where this behavior was defined. False leads include:

- /proc/acpi/lid.sh
- "HandleLidSwitch" in /etc/systemd/logind.conf

Most strangely, I installed ZSH today on the Probook (usually a Bash guy, wanted to give it a shot) and it started lock + suspend on lid close, with the same `gnome-screensaver-command -l` behavior as the T460s.

I uninstalled and re-installed ZSH and it disappeared, now it just suspends without locking.

Comment: An answer can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059705/keep-a-laptop-running-with-closed-lid/1059712#1059712