# Keep a laptop running with closed lid

Tags: power-management, lock-screen, user-management

I am trying to keep my laptop running with the lid closed.

What I've done so far is:

1. In the file `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` add `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` both for docked and plain mode.  This didn't do the trick at all.
2. In the file `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` set `IgnoreLid=true`

This worked, but now my TeamViewer session closes and the screen is locked, so I still can't actually use the laptop.

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid

Answer (score 12):

## Command line based

There are some **gsettings** you can use:

- **Handling when on ac line**

  ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'nothing'
  ```

  This will disable any action when the lid gets closed, **and** the laptop is plugged into AC.
  To undo simply:

  ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'suspend'
  ```

  Possible setting values instead of suspend are:

  > 'blank', 'suspend', 'shutdown','hibernate', 'interactive', 'nothing', 'logout'
- **Handling when on battery**

  ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'nothing'
  ```
- **Handling when an external monitor is plugged in**

  ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor 'nothing'
  ```

## Using a gui

If you prefer a gui based solution, you have to install

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Invoke with

```
dconf-editor&
```

or by searching the program dash.

Go to the `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/lid-close-ac-action` **schema** as show in the first line of the images shown above, and make your settings:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clear, well documented, reply.  Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem  I think the problem is not with the power management but is related to user/log in management killing my session when the lid closes.  Or am I looking in the wrong direction?

Comment: @abu_bua I think you need to upload image again ;-)

Comment: @Hades, regardless if this solved your problem, abu_bua's answer answered your question. Either accept this and make a new question describing the problem or edit your question.

Comment: no lid options exist in my menu.

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu 19.10 the `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-*` actions don't seem to work any more.

## Keep on running on lid-close instead of *suspend*

Edit the file `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` with `sudo` and change the line

```
#HandleLidSwitch=.....
```

to

```
HandleLidSwitch=lock
```

And reboot your system.

---

The file `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` controls how logind shall handle the system power and sleep keys and the lid switch to trigger actions such as system power-off or suspend. Can be one of
*"ignore", "poweroff", "reboot", "halt", "kexec", "suspend", "hibernate", "hybrid-sleep", "suspend-then-hibernate", and "lock".* for these settings:

```
 HandlePowerKey=, HandleSuspendKey=, HandleHibernateKey=, HandleLidSwitch=,
 HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=, HandleLidSwitchDocked=
```

Reference:

- http://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/04/28/change-lid-close-action-ubuntu-18-04-lts/
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man5/logind.conf.5.html

Comment: Yes working but when I reopened the laptop it changes the resolution of the screen on the higher one!

Comment: What do you mean with higher one? Do you use two screens?

Comment: My actual screen resolution is 1600x900, if I close the laptop when I reopen it I get the login screen at 1920x1080 and once logged Gnome has this resolution. I am using only one screen.

Comment: As a workaround I would call a script to restore the desired resolution on resume: https://askubuntu.com/q/204073/34298

Answer (score 0):

Install [GNOME Tweaks](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-tweaks). Pull up the user interface and find:

[image]

It shouldn't be too hard to figure out what to do:

[image]

Close GNOME tweaks to register the change (before testing).