# Lock Screen on closing lid(not suspend) Ubuntu 16.04 gnome

Tags: gnome, suspend, lock-screen

I was previously using Ubuntu 16.04 Unity. I changed to gnome. Earlier it used to lock the screen when I closed the lid. I could listen to music without any trouble. Now on closing the lid it suspends the system(music stops). I tried editing the /etc/systemd/logind.conf (changing HandleLidSwitch=lock) but it didnt work. I also tried using Tweak Tool, that too didnt work.

Comment: did you restart systemd after editing logind.conf? `systemctl restart systemd-logind.service`?

Comment: yes. anyways now i have upgraded to 18.04 in which the lid close function works fine.

Comment: maybe this link is useful for you https://askubuntu.com/a/1059712/790920

Comment: @abu_bua that's not really helpful as when I reach the schema(as described), I clicked on lid-close-ac-action, then on Custom Settings, BUT the main problem here is that there is no sleep option.