# When closing the lid of my laptop nothing happens instead of suspend)

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management, laptop, lid

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on my Lenovo Thinkpad L560. When I close the lid nothing happens. I want the system to suspend. The settings for this are turned on. So when I close my lid and reopen it nothing has happened. I'm not logged out or anything.

Can you help me?

Comment: Try to check gsettings -> https://askubuntu.com/a/1059712/790920

Comment: I found the solution myself. I followed these steps: http://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/04/28/change-lid-close-action-ubuntu-18-04-lts/ but I was stupied i tried to edit the file before but I didn't see the "#" for the line to be a comment. After removing the "'#" it works!

Answer (score 1):

These instructions follows [this tips page](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/04/28/change-lid-close-action-ubuntu-18-04-lts/):

Enable automatic shutdown, hibernate, or do nothing when laptop lid is closed.

1. Edit the `logind.conf` file

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf
   ```
2. Uncomment the following line (delete the `#` character):

   ```
   #HandleLidSwitch=suspend
   ```

   to

   ```
   HandleLidSwitch=suspend
   ```
3. Save the file and finally restart the `systemd` service:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind.service
   ```

Comment: Not working on Lenovo T430, sadly

Comment: This works perfect, but unfortunately it does not make distinction between battery/ac-in situation - is there any chance making it suspend when running on battery and doing nothing when ac is plugged in?