# Ubuntu only shows mouse cursor and wallpaper after opening laptop?

Tags: nvidia, display, suspend, laptop, macbook-pro

After changing a config setting to make my (partitioned Macbook Pro) laptop do nothing when the lid is closed ('HandleLidSwitch=ignore'), but now, when I open my laptop again, nothing is shown except the wallpaper and my mouse cursor.

It seems I can still open apps by pressing the "command" key on my laptop and then searching for apps and pressing enter, and a new terminal window *will* appear, but no sidebar is showing, nor are the icons on my desktop.

Any fixes for this?

Comment: Do you know exactly what is the _config setting_ you made? If you can access a terminal run `journalctl -p err` Copy here the parts you may found relevant.

Comment: @PabloBianchi I edited the "/etc/systemd/logind.conf" file. I uncommented the HandleLidSwitch= option and changed "suspend" to "ignore"

Comment: What if you undo those changes? Take a look to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1059705/349837)

Answer (score 0):

FIXED!!!

Turns out the problem was that Ubuntu thought I had 2 displays connected, when in reality I had one.
When I would open the laptop, it would display the interface and sidebar and all that on the "main monitor", which wasn't my laptop screen.

To fix this I simply restarted my computer and then removed the second display